# Basis for set of matrices with trace not equal 0

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Basis set of matrices with trace 0 can be like that
$$\{E_{ij}:1\le i,j\le n \land i\ne j\}\cup\{E_{ii}-E_{i+1,i+1}:1\le i<n\}$$
this set contains $n^2-1$ elements, so space of $n\times n$ matrices with trace 0 is $n^2-1$ dimensional. Space of all matrices $n\times n$ is $n^2$ dimensional and set of matrices with trace equals 0 and not equals 0 are distinct so this should be true: ?
$$\dim M = \dim M_{t=0} + \dim M_{t\ne 0}$$
where $M$ - Set of all matrices, $M_{t=0}$ - set of matrices with trace 0 and $M_{t\ne 0}$ - set of matrices with trace not equal 0. 
$$n^2 = (n^2-1)+(1)$$
So, $$\dim M_{t\ne 0}=1$$
thats correct?

Comment: What makes you think that the set of traceful matrices is a subspace?

Comment: Right.... Thanks! :)

Comment: What does $\dim X$ mean when $X$ is not a linear or affine space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not correct. The reason is that the set of matrices with non-zero trace is not a subspace, as can be seen by the simple fact that the zero matrix does not lie in that set. Indeed, if $V$ is any vector space, and $U$ is a subspace of $V$, then $V\setminus U$ is *never* a subspace of $V$.

However you can do a very similar decomposition:

$$M = M_{t=0} + \mathbb{R}I$$

where $I$ is the identity matrix. Both $M_{t=0}$ and $\mathbb RI$ are subspaces, and they are linearly independent (and even orthogonal under the Hilbert-Schmidt scalar product). Therefore you can write any matrix $A$ uniquely as
$$A = X + \lambda I$$
where $X\in M_{t=0}$ and $\lambda$ determines the trace (more exactly, $\operatorname{tr}A = \lambda/\!\dim M$). Clearly, $\mathbb RI$ has dimension 1.